How to filter Excel list using data validation lists and matrix
I have a table of document names in the first column, and users in the following columns. I'm using the rows beneath each user to assign them documents to review. The list is quite long and I'd like to filter out only the rows that contain "X" for the user selected in the dropdown list. Is this possible in Excel?
Example list


Try using the following formula:


=FILTER(A3:A5,MMULT((B1=D1:F1)*(D3:F5="X"),{1;1;1}))


To make it more dynamic replace these {1;1;1} with the following SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D1:F1))^0:
=FILTER(A3:A5,MMULT((B1=D1:F1)*(D3:F5="X"),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(D1:F1))^0))



This is exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I'd like to clean up, if possible, is that I have 47 names and the only way I could figure it out was to add 47 1s to the second matrix. Is there a cleaner way that would be easier to adapt to changes in number of names?

@TexxK sorry for the delay in response, I wasn't in front of the computer. Updated now.
